# Angular Date Range Picker not able to implement

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to create a date range picker in Angular 7 with the help of angular material. But whenever I click on the calendar, the value is not updated on the input field. I'm sharing my code below.

As, you can see from the code below, I have written a click function on the second input field. On clicking it opens up two calendars, one for start date, other for end date. But, whenever, I try to click on any date, it saves only today's date. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

input-overview-example.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="strtpicker" [value]="date.value" placeholder="Start Date" >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="ml-20">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="endpicker" [value]="date.value"  placeholder="Choose a date" (click)="dateRange()">
</mat-form-field>

<div class="d-flex" *ngIf="show">
    <mat-card >
      <p>Start Date</p>
      <mat-calendar ></mat-calendar>
    </mat-card>
   <mat-card>
     <p>End Date</p>
      <mat-calendar></mat-calendar>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

input-overview-example.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatDatepickerInputEvent} from '@angular/material/datepicker';



/**
 * @title Basic Inputs
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
})
export class InputOverviewExample {
   events: string[] = [];
     addEvent(type: string, event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    this.events.push(`${type}: ${event.value}`);
  }

  date = new FormControl(new Date());


  show: boolean;

   dateRange() {
    this.show = true;
  }

}
```

Comment: well, you need two formControls or a formGroup with two formControls. to use a formControl alone, use `[formControl]="date"`, NOT [value]="date.value", to use a formGroup see @kris Hollenbeck answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have the calendars separated from the control. But here I've created an example illustrating how you can track the data using a date picker range component and a form group. Essentially combining the examples from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) and [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Essentially the inputs need to be hooked up to a model to keep track of the changes.

**datepicker-overview-example.ts**

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatDatepickerInputEvent} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

/** @title Basic datepicker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-overview-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}

  public startDate;
  public endDate;
  public dateForm = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(),
    end: new FormControl(),
  });

  update() {
    this.startDate = this.dateForm.get('start').value;
    this.endDate = this.dateForm.get('end').value;
  }
}
```

**datepicker-overview-example.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="dateForm">
  <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="start" placeholder="Start Date" formControlName="start" (dateChange)=update()>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="start"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #start></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="end" placeholder="End Date" formControlName="end" (dateChange)=update()>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="end"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #end></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

<h3>Model Output</h3>
<div>
  <p>Start: {{startDate}}</p>
  <p>End: {{endDate}}</p>
</div>
```

**Demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skq67a

Comment: Whatever you have implemented is good. But, my requirement is little bit different. When I click on the input field, both the calendars should pop out. Form the first calendar, the date should populate in the first input field and from the second calendar, the input should populate in the second input field.